# Destroying activity causes service to lose data

Tags: java, android

Whenever my application is minimized I start a service that is sending pull requests to my HTTP server to check for notifications, when the application is brought back up the service gets terminated (along with the scheduled runnable). All works well until I decided to kill the application (slide it off the screen from the running apps list). Then for some reason the properties of the service get reset (even the static ones) and `onStartCommand` gets called again with it's first parameter `Intent` as `null` which is weird for me.

Here are some parts of the code

```
public class DnActivity extends Activity {

    protected String cookieString = "";
    protected String userAgent = "";
    protected WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, PullService.class);
            mServiceIntent.putExtra("cookieString", cookieString);
            mServiceIntent.putExtra("userAgent", userAgent);
            startService(mServiceIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("DNev", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, PullService.class);
        stopService(mServiceIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                try {
                    cookieString = getCookieFromAppCookieManager(url);
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    Log.e("DNev", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the service

```
public class PullService extends Service {

    protected static String cookieString;
    protected static String userAgent = "Mobile APP for Android";
    protected Service PullService = this;
    protected ScheduledFuture interval;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null) {
            if (intent.hasExtra("cookieString")) {
                cookieString = intent.getStringExtra("cookieString");
            }
            if (intent.hasExtra("userAgent")) {
                userAgent = intent.getStringExtra("userAgent");
            }
        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        interval.cancel(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.d("DNev", String.valueOf(cookieString));
        Log.d("DNev", String.valueOf(userAgent));

        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        interval = scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.d("DNev", "1");
                Log.d("DNev", String.valueOf(cookieString));
                Log.d("DNev", String.valueOf(userAgent));

                ...
```

As I said, everything works fine until I destroy the activity, then the `interval` keeps running but `cookieString` and `userAgent` become their default values.

I need to be able to persist these values when the activity gets destroyed, how can I do that?

I'm not experienced in neither android nor java development, and I want to apologize if my code made anyone cry blood.

Here is the manifest entry for the service, it resides in `<application`

```
<service  android:name=".PullService" android:exported="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> All works well until I decided to kill the application (slide it off the screen from the running apps list).

When you kill the app (which I assume `Force Stop` from i.e. Settings -> Apps) then WHOLE app gets terminated, including its services. Everything stored in variables will go away with the process. If you want it to survive, you need to store it in persistent storage (i.e. in database or shared preferences).

Also I'd save this data once I received it, in `onStartCommand()` because if  `onDestroy()` will not be called (which is not unlikely for abruptly killed process) then your data would be lost.

> I start a service that is sending pull requests to my HTTP server to check for notifications

Don't. Use GCM to actually push notification to the app. Do not pull.

Comment: But if everything gets destroyed then how come the service keeps running?

Comment: Added, sorry for the delay.

Comment: You said it keeps running but isn't your service *recreated* (i.e. you see in logs entries from `onCreate()`? Can you show code for your scheduled runnable?

Comment: Yes, it appears to be recreated with a `null` Intent, which is confusing for me, how is it being recreated without an intent?

Comment: Obviously I don't have a good-enough understanding of how things work because this makes no sense for me. Anyway I just created a database and solved the problem, but I was hoping I could go without one.

Comment: You can use shared preferences. That's perfectly valid approach for what you are storing just two strings

Comment: When you kill the app (how exactly you do), can you see logs from your runnable? and what is your runnable doing?

Answer (score 0):

in the `DnActivity.onDestroy()` method, save the info somewhere, you could have the "shutting down" of the activity control the `mServiceIntent` and do alterations to it (like shutting it down as well)

For instance:

```
DnActivity.onDestroy(){
   super.onDestroy();
   stopService(mServiceIntent);
   Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, PullService.class);
        mServiceIntent.putExtra("some_value", the_value);
        mServiceIntent.putExtra("some_other_value", the_other_value);
   startService(mServiceIntent);
}
```

Comment: @php_nub_qq Have you just copy/pasted it? it wont work. You have to add the onDestroy method to the DnActivity class. Also, I just shut down, then up, the service, check if that is what you really want. When you "swipe off the screen" you are calling the onPause/onDestroy of your activity. It is then, when you must close connections, save stuff, etc on your data that must persist